# Button of user control file not working in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, user-controls

I have a user control file containing sign-in and sign-up button. This file is loaded to the master page. Now I have another page called test.aspx which implements the master page such that the the sign in and sign up button of  user control file (header.ascx) is automatically loaded in the test.aspx. However the sign-in button gives NO reaction on clicking?

Comment: its hard to help you without looking at code. Could post some code?

Comment: First of all thank you for your concern.I figured out the problem but not exactly.Now the senerio is that the button of usercontrol file works fine when i remove all the bootstrap components.But when i include them the "onclick" dosent work.

Comment: First of all thank you for your concern.I figured out the problem but not exactly.Now the senerio is that the button of usercontrol file works fine when i remove all the bootstrap components.But when i include them the "onclick" dosent work. I tried to post the code as well but it says too long.I am new here and dosent know much.For now the problem is how to integrate bootstrap with asp.net.

Comment: Maybe you can change the onClick to call JavaScript function, then use WebMethods to call C#.. What is the markup for the Login-button? Did you integrate boostrap CSS class? CssClass="form-control"

Comment: uhh...i am getting some result.The problem is now solved.The mistake  was that i had modified the jquery file.I removed the jquery file and included fresh jquery file.Now all is well.Thank you for your concern.